# Print document and attach event for printer spooler

Tags: c#, system.printing

I want to print a document (in the default printer) and be able to track it's printing job, so i will be able to see if the job was sent to the spooler, and that it was actually printed and not canceled for some reason. 
I want to catch the print job event and follow every step until it is successfully (or not - and if so what is the reason) printed.

I've searched for a solution for this, but i didn't get anything to work for me..
what is the best way to implement this? is there a good example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already covered most of what you need by tagging this System.Printing - assuming you are using version 3.0 or better of the .net runtime then the System.Printing namespace is [pretty well documented on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.aspx)